# How to find the reserves of each coin pair on the pancakeswap coinPair smart contract

Tags: contract-invocation, pancakeswap, binance

I am trying to calculate the reserves of each coin in the pool of a coin pair at a given time.
using the https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/pairs API, I can't seem to find that value.
the API does return some good data but not the current reserve.
this is what the API returns :

```
{

    base_address: 0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82
    base_name: PancakeSwap Token
    base_symbol: Cake
    base_volume: 3742427.017298731802757169
    liquidity: 1624503535.402908378290691194641887
    liquidity_BNB: 2641659.327503843701997896
    pair_address: 0x0eD7e52944161450477ee417DE9Cd3a859b14fD0
    price: 0.06342180375934548959
    quote_address: 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c
    quote_name: Wrapped BNB
    quote_symbol: WBNB
    quote_volume: 245324.64910932273403908

}
```

can someone please tell me how to calculate the reserves of each Token ? is there a way to do that with the smart contract event logs like Sync, swap, and transfer?

Comment: This Reddit post has a good write up on the subject. https://www.reddit.com/r/pancakeswap/comments/mwz72v/is_there_a_way_to_monitor_the_price_on_pancake/